# How to loop through rows of a column containing strings and email these strings?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column 'A' in excel containing Names of books, I am trying to loop through  all the rows and email each name to the email id in the adjacent cell(same row, column 'B'). How can I loop through the different rows to access the strings contained in these cells?

```
Sub Sendmail()        
    Dim answer As String
    Dim SubmitLink_BookName As String
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set KeyCells = Range("F2:F10") 'Range of 'Y/N' for whole column

    answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to save this change. An Email will be sent to the User", vbYesNo, "Save the change")

    If answer = vbNo Then Cancel = True
    If answer = vbYes Then
        For i = 2 To 20 'i corresponds to row number
            SubmitLink_BookName = Range("A2").Value  'HELP- SubmitLink contains content appropriate cell- need help here

            'Open Outlook
            Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
            Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
            Set newmsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            'Add recipient
            newmsg.Recipients.Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
            'Add subject
            newmsg.Subject = "Book: " & SubmitLink_BookName & "." 'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F1").Value
            'Add body
            newmsg.Body = "Book" & SubmitLink_BookName 

            'Display
            newmsg.Display
            newmsg.Send
            MsgBox "Modification confirmd", , "Confirmation"


            End If
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you mean`... = Range("A" & i).Value`?  Or, it seems you're thinking of it using `Cells([row], [column])`, `... = Cells(i, "A").Value`.

Comment: The `End If` right **before** `Next i` is too much and should throw an error? Please clarify and correct ([edit]) the code in your question.

Comment: Please tell us what is **not working** with your code.

Comment: Basically, I am asking about the syntax (for the range function) for how to change the "A2" within: SubmitLink_BookName = Range("A2").Value so that I can store the contents of many different cells turn by turn by using a loop to loop through the rows of the same column, and save it in this string (SubmitLink_BookName ).

Comment: I think this may be possible with .Offset somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Worksheet.Cells property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells) `Cells(row, column)` instead of the `Range("A1")` and give it a try `SubmitLink_BookName = Cells(i, "A").Value`

Note that if you name your variables more meaningfull eg. `iRow` instead of `i` then you don't need to comment `'i corresponds to row number` because you instantly see this information. More meaningful names make your life easier.

Also always specify in which workbook your `cells` or `range` is: `Worksheets("MySheet").Range("A1").Value`

Another issue is that you should use `Option Explicit` because then you will see that your `olMailItem` is not working correctly. You can only use it if you set a reference to the Outlook library in the VB Editor menu › Extras › References, but not if you are using late binding `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` only.

Also I would move the creating of the Outlook Application out of your loop. Otherwise you create 20 Outlooks. Also don't forget to destroy it in the end.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Sendmail()
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'define worksheet to use it for all Range and Cells
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Set KeyCells = ws.Range("F2:F10") 'Range of 'Y/N' for whole column

    Dim Answer As String
    Answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to save this change. An Email will be sent to the User", vbYesNo, "Save the change")


    Dim SubmitLink_BookName As String

    If Answer <> vbYes Then
        Dim OutlookApp As Object
        Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

        Dim OlObjects As Object
        Set OlObjects = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        Dim NewMsg As Object

        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = 2 To 20
            SubmitLink_BookName = ws.Cells(iRow, "A").Value

            Set NewMsg = OutlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            'Add recipient
            NewMsg.Recipients.Add ws.Cells(iRow, "B").Value
            'Add subject
            NewMsg.Subject = "Book: " & SubmitLink_BookName & "." 'ws.Range("F1").Value
            'Add body
            NewMsg.Body = "Book" & SubmitLink_BookName

            'Display
            NewMsg.Display
            NewMsg.Send
            MsgBox "Modification confirmd", , "Confirmation"
        Next iRow

        OutlookApp.Quit 'don't forget to end the outlook app you created
        Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```